# Do catalysts themselves need an input of energy to work?

Tags: catalysis

Do catalysts themselves need an input of energy to work?

My book says "catalysts do not per se require an energy source". What does it mean by per se? If they don't use energy how do they activate?

Comment: Come to think of it, do the _reactants_ need energy?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Well then what is the _activation_ energy? I always thought of it as the minimum energy needed to be supplied to the _reactants_ ...

Comment: The word "supplied" may be misleading. We don't have to supply anything, since thermal energy is already there. If it isn't, then of course we have zero K and no reaction.